# Tree_view undefined after read kendo tree

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, kendo-treeview

Here's my problem:

I load a first time my tree to display him.
I can change the value of the Session's files name "state" to enable or disable a node in my tree.

But after I change ne value in my database and return the JSON, I read again the tree to refresh my tree with the changes but it's failed and write in console :
" TypeError: Tree_view.getElementsByClassName(...)[0].children[(item.id_perso - 1)].children[1] is undefined".

That I don't understand is I pass my first time by these functions and it work well, but when I reload it failed apparently because the it undefined.

Thank's for any help.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Tree_view').kendoTreeView({
        template: "#= item.name #",
        dataSource: Parcours,
        dataTextField: 'name',
        loadOnDemand: true,
        expand: onExpandedItem
    });
});

function onExpandedItem(e) {

    var id_user = @Model.id;

    var item =  $('#Tree_view').data('kendoTreeView').dataItem(e.node);
    var treeview = $('#Tree_view').data('kendoTreeView');
    var type = item.fields.type;

    if (item.level() > 0) {
        item.id_parcours = item.parentNode().id_parcours;
        if (item.level() == 2) {
            item.id_promo = item.parentNode().id;
        }
    }
    else item.id_parcours = item.Id;

    switch (type) {
        case 'parcours':
            item.children.transport.options.read = {
                url: '@Url.Action("Get_Session", "Users")' + '?user_id=' + id_user,
                dataType: "json",
            };
            break;

        case 'session':
            item.children.transport.options.read = {
                url: '@Url.Action("Get_Matiere")' + '?user_id=' + id_user,
                dataType: "json"
            };
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    if (item.level() == 0) {
        setTimeout(function() { waitDisable(item, treeview); }, 1000);
    }
}

function waitDisable(item, treeview) {
    if (item.fields.type == "parcours")
    {
        var node = Tree_view.getElementsByClassName('k-group')[0].children[item.id_perso - 1].children[1].children;
        for (i = 0; i < item.children._data.length; i ++)
        {
            if (item.children._data[i].state != null) {
                node[i].children[0].children[1].className = "k-in k-state-disabled";
                node[i].children[0].children[0].className = ".k-icon-remove";
            }
            else node[i].children[0].children[0].className = "k-icon k-plus";

            addRow(node, item, i, treeview);
        }
    }
}

var cmp = 0;
var One_Time = false;

function addRow(node_Here, item, i, treeview) {

    var actual_row = node_Here[i].children[0];
    if (actual_row.childNodes.length < 3) {
        var newSpan = document.createElement('button');
        if (item.children._data[i]._childrenOptions.data.state != null) {
            newSpan.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Re-Up"));
            newSpan.className = "change_state btn btn-success btn-xs";
        }
        else {
            newSpan.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Down"));
            newSpan.className = "change_state btn btn-danger btn-xs";
        }
        actual_row.appendChild(newSpan);
    }
    cmp += 1;
    if (cmp == item.children._data.length)
        One_Time = true;
    if (One_Time) {
        addClickListner(item, i, treeview);
        One_Time = false;
        cmp = 0;
    }
}

function addClickListner(item, i, treeview) {
    $(".change_state").click(function (event) {
        var name_Promo_Rm = event.target.parentNode.children[1].textContent;
        var User_Select = event.view.Parcours.transport.read.data.user_id;
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ChangeStatutBase", "Users")',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { Name_Promo: name_Promo_Rm, User_id: User_Select },
        });
        refreshTree(treeview);
    })
}

// Refresh tree
function refreshTree(treeview) {
    // Save open items
    saveExpandedItems(treeview);
    // Reload data source
    treeview.dataSource.read();
    // Load open items
    console.log("OKKKKKKK");
    setTimeout(loadExpandedItems(), 600);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved my problem, in the "setTimeout" in the bottom I've placed "()" in the first parameter and it doesn't put the pause and data don't have the time to be loaded.